# Spiraling number in Array - Stack Overflow with large numbers

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, stack, overflow

I need to add the pivot points in a spiral array as follows:

```
 21 22 23 24 25
 20  7  8  9 10
 19  6  1  2 11
 18  5  4  3 12
 17 16 15 14 13
```

I have the java code to do just that, and it works fine with a small 5x5 array like shown above... But when I test it with a large 1001x1001 array it gives me a lot of stack overflows. I don't know how to track it, I already used try and catch without success. The code is below. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
public class Spiral {
    int[][] arr = new int[1001][1001];
    int counter = 1;
    public int total = 1;
    String direction = "SOUTH";
    public Spiral(){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        try {
        arr[500][500] = 1;
        spiral(500, 501);
        total += arr[0][arr.length - 1];
        System.out.println(total);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
        }
    }

    public void spiral(int x, int y) {

            counter++;
            arr[x][y] = counter;

            if(x==900&&y==900)
                System.out.println("here");
            if (direction == "SOUTH") {
                if (arr[x][y - 1] != 0) {
                    if (x + 1 < arr.length)
                    spiral(x + 1, y);
                } else {
                    total += arr[x][y];
                    direction = "WEST";
                    spiral(x, y - 1);
                }
            } else if (direction == "WEST") {
                if (arr[x - 1][y] != 0) {
                    if (y - 1 >= 0) {
                        spiral(x, y - 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    total += arr[x][y];
                    direction = "NORTH";
                    spiral(x - 1, y);
                }
            } else if (direction == "NORTH") {
                if (arr[x][y + 1] != 0) {
                    if (x - 1 >= 0) {
                        spiral(x - 1, y);
                    }
                } else {
                    total += arr[x][y];
                    direction = "EAST";
                    spiral(x, y + 1);
                }
            } else if (direction == "EAST") {
                if (arr[x + 1][y] != 0) {
                    if (y + 1 < arr.length) {
                        spiral(x, y + 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    total += arr[x][y - 1];
                    direction = "SOUTH";
                    spiral(x + 1, y);
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: are you intentionally comparing strings with the == operator? this is a address comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

spiral(int, int) is recursive, and is calling itself so many times that it is overflowing the stack.  You have two options:

1. Refactor your algorithm to loop instead of recurse
2. Increase your stack size using the vm arg -Xss.  By default the vm uses 512 KB for the stack, so you could try using -Xss1m to double that size (or any other value you might need)

Comment: I really recommend you to choose option 1 as very deep recursion usually isn't a good idea.

Comment: Agreed.  Options 2 is easier, but is more of a band-aid.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm recurs for every cell in your array .  Is your stack really big enough to recur 1,002,001 times?  If not then you'll have to either make your stack bigger or try a different algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you're seeing this problem because of how your recursion works. You are calling `spiral` recursively to print out your data, but when calling it with a 1001x1001 data set, you are creating a stack trace that is also that big, causing your JVM to crash and ultimately it gives you that Stack Overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using recursion , it is obvious that you will get StackOverFlow exception for large inputs.

Try tuning the vm with with -Xss switch.